# Getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, mern, passport-local

I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined while attempting to register any user to the database using a post request via postman on route http:localhost:3000/signup, I searched for similar errors and tried the following:
1- installing and using bodyparser and using it on server.js
2- declaring express session before passport initialization and declaration of passport.session

and i use body to pass json data to the route on postman [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdcyV.png)

/backend/routes/signup.js

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");

 const User = require("../models/users").default;


router.route("/signup").get((req, res) => {
    res.render("/signup");
});



router.route("/signup").post((req, res) => {
  const registeredUser = {
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email
  }

  User.register(registeredUser, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { 
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        res.json("User registered");
        res.redirect("/notes/:username");
        // redirect user or do whatever you want
    });
  }
     // Value 'result' is set to false. The user could not be authenticated since the user is not active
    });
  });
      
        // const newUser = new User({
        //   firstName,
        //   lastName,
        //   username,
        //   email,
        //   password
        // });
        // newUser.save()
        // .then(() => res.json("User " + username + " is registered to database!"))
        // .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error" + err

   



module.exports = router;
```

/backend/server.js

```js
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const User = require("./models/users");
const Note = require("./models/notes");


const notesRouter = require("./routes/notes");
const registerRouter =  require("./routes/signup");
const loginRouter = require("./routes/signin");

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors()); 

app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use( bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
  extended: true
}));   

app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret:"This is keeper clone",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("MongoDb database connection established successfully");
});


app.use("/", notesRouter);
app.use("/", registerRouter);
app.use("/", loginRouter);



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000!");
});
```

/backend/models/users.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String
    }
},

    {
        timestamps: true,
    
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


module.exports = User;
```

I have previously used the same approach in another project and it worked fine for me

```js
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
  secret: "Our little secret.",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  secret: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);

    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/secrets"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ["profile"] })
);

app.get("/auth/google/secrets",
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect to secrets.
    res.redirect("/secrets");
  });

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/secrets',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/secrets',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }));



app.get("/login", function(req, res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res){
  User.find({"secret": {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUsers){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUsers) {
        res.render("secrets", {usersWithSecrets: foundUsers});
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/submit", function(req, res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("submit");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.post("/submit", function(req, res){
  const submittedSecret = req.body.secret;

//Once the user is authenticated and their session gets saved, their user details are saved to req.user.
  // console.log(req.user.id);

  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUser) {
        foundUser.secret = submittedSecret;
        foundUser.save(function(){
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){

  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/register");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });

});

app.post("/login", function(req, res){

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });

});







app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by just removing .default from the User import statement in route file

```js
const User = require("../models/users").default;
```

```js
const User = require("../models/users");
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `register` function of `User` Model

```
 User.register(registeredUser, req.body.password, function(err, user)
```

but you don't defined it, for defined register method in mongoose, you can use this [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) or use `static` method in mognoose

Comment: If you please take another look on my question, I have added another code snippet where I used the same approach on another project without defining register method as a custom method for mongoose model and it was working fine.